# savoir vs connaître

Tags: choix-de-mot

What's the difference between savoir and connaître?
for example:

> 1. je sais la mer Méditerranée vs je connais la mer Méditerranée
> 2. je ne sais pas la réponse vs je ne connais pas la réponse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Savoir" means a deeper knowledge than "connaître". I.e. you cannot say "Je sais la mer Méditerranée".

> Je connais ce poème = I have heard about this poem,
>   Je sais ce poème = I know the text by heart